# References on obtaining experimental observables from band structure

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, resource-recommendations, observables, electronic-band-theory

I've recently been watching [this lecture series](https://pirsa.org/C22002) in Condensed Matter physics. We have covered second quantization, used it to obtain the tight-binding model and then studied the band structure of various different lattices using these techniques. The last few classes I've watched were on how to obtain experimental observables from band structure (i.e., from the expression $E(\vec{k})$ for the single-particle energies of the lattice). These observables were specific heat, electric conductivity, and thermal conductivity. However, I couldn't quite grasp the explanations given in the course and would like some other references to check and see if things get clearer.

I'm mainly focused on computing these three quantities (specific heat, electric conductivity, and thermal conductivity) from $E(\vec{k})$, but I particularly welcome books and references that also include nice discussions about second quantization and the tight-binding model in the second quantization formalism.

Comment: These do not seem to be actually related to 2nd quantisation. It seems to be more related to extracting physical variables from single-particle assumptions present in band model, and you might find much simpler arguments of them in introductions to solid state physics, e.g. Kittel, Ashcroft & Mermin, and friends.

Comment: I don't know if this is what you mean (probably not because there is no emphasize on the TB model), but you could also check some more advanced Green's functions methods, which describe e.g. ARPES experiments and so on; from that you can also extract the band structure. There are plenty of books and online resources. I remember you work on relativistic QFTs, right? You will recognize that these are the same methods and have very similar interpretations (e.g. spectral functions, (quasi)particles etc.). You can then calculate all sorts of observables, extend to finite temperature and so on...

Comment: @TobiasFünke Yes, I work on relativistic QFTs. That seems like an interesting idea. Thank you very much!